# How does a totally complex polarization induce a Kähler structure of the symplectic manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, quantum-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

A totally complex polarization of a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ is a subbundle $F$ of the complexified tangent bundle $TM_{\mathbb C}:=TM\oplus iTM$ such that

- $F$ is integrable in the sense that Lie brackets of sections of $F$ are still sections of $F$,
- every fiber $F_x$ is a Langrangian subspace of $T_xM_{\mathbb C}$, i.e. $\dim_{\mathbb C}F_x=\dim M/2$ and $\omega(Z,W)=0$, $\forall Z,W\in F_x$,
- $F_x\cap\bar F_x=\{0\}$, $\forall x$ (and hence $F\oplus\bar F=TM_{\mathbb C}$).

It is said in some books or lectures on geometric quantization e.g. [Bate and Weinstein's](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ealanw/GofQ.pdf), there is a complex structure $J$ compatible with the symplectic form $\omega$ such that $F=\{X+iJX|\ X\in TM\}$. It is clear that $J$ **has to be defined by multiplying by** $-i$ **on** $F$ **and by** $i$ **on** $\bar F$. Then such $J$ preserves the real tangent bundle $TM$ and the symplectic form $\omega$. But I don't know **how to prove that the symmmetric bilinear form** $\omega(-,J-)$ **is a positive definite metric on** $TM$.

Moreover it seems to me that there is a simple 'counterexample' in $(\mathbb R^4,\omega:=dx^1\wedge dx^3+dx^2\wedge dx^4)$ where the totally complex polarization $F$ is spanned by vector fields $Z:=\partial/\partial x^1+i\partial/\partial x^2$ and $\partial/\partial x^4-i\partial/\partial x^3$. Then $J\partial/\partial x^1=J(\bar Z+Z)/2=i(\bar Z-Z)/2=\partial/\partial x^2$ hence $\omega(\partial/\partial x^1,J\partial/\partial x^1)=0$. So where is this 'counterexample' wrong?

Comment: Where did you find the statement that a totally complex polarization induces a Kähler structure? (You are right that the bilinear form $\omega( - , J- )$ need not be positive-definite.)

Comment: Sometimes the positivity of $\omega(\cdot,J\cdot)$ is *part of the definition of compatibility* between a complex structure $J$ (or an almost complex one) with a symplectic form $\omega$. Could this be the case in that book?

Comment: Thank you Peter. I found the statement in Page 101 of Bate and Weinstein's book above. Maybe I misunderstood the context.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Johnny.